# Angular startup service factory never gets called

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, ngrx

I have a startup service that I am using in my angular app. This is being used to call my rest API and give the user the url-address.

I have a startup.service.ts file, an app.config.json file and a web.config file which is shown below:

```
//startup.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError as _throw } from 'rxjs';

export interface Configuration {
  api: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class StartupService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  private _startupData: Configuration;

  load(): Observable<Configuration> {
    const data = this.httpClient.get<Configuration>('app.config.json').pipe(
      map(config => config),
      catchError((error: any) => _throw(error))
    );
    data.subscribe(d => {
      this._startupData = d;
    });
    return data;
  }

  get startupData(): Configuration {
    return this._startupData;
  }
}
```

---

```
//app.config.json
{
  "api": "http://localhost:64403/api/status"
}
```

---

```
//web.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/home/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In my app module I have added the following code

```
//app.module.ts
export function startupServiceFactory(
  startupService: StartupService
): Function {
  return () => {
    startupService.load();
  };
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, NotFoundComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    VehicleStatusModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    LeafletModule.forRoot(),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(effects),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StartupService,
    {
      // Provider for APP_INITIALIZER
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: startupServiceFactory,
      deps: [StartupService],
      multi: true
    },
    // router state composition
    { provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomSerializer }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And whenever I run the app I get the following error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'api' of undefined

coming from my app.service.ts. It should return the string: "http://localhost:64403/api/status"

```
//app.service.ts
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class VehicleService {

  private API_URL = this.startupService.startupData.fleetApi;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService,
    private startupService: StartupService
  ) {}
```

The thing that makes me even more confused is that this used to work a few days ago, but after I added my NGRX store, it stopped working and gave me the error above. My debugging tells me that the startup service factory isnt being called. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Please let me know if there is anything that you want me to clarify.

Comment: `so every user dont have to build the angular project themselves` : what does that mean ?

Comment: @trichetriche I thought this was one of the reasons for bootstrapping.

Comment: Again : what does that mean ?

Comment: @trichetriche that multiple users can use the same url without causing conflict.

Comment: Since when does it create conflict to use the same URL ? If it did, the internet would not exist ...

Comment: @trichetriche Im just reciting things Ive heard. What are you trying to accomplish with this? Im here because Im lost.

Comment: I'm here to understand your need and provide an answer adapted to your case. But if I don't even understand what you're saying, how can I help you ? And it seems you're just repeating hearsays. So bottom line : don't repeat things you hear. Now, could you please tell me what are you trying to achieve, so that I can point you in the right direction ?

Comment: @trichetriche The issue was that my this.startupService.startupData.api returned undefined. I did some debugging and realized that my startupServiceFactory wasnt being called at all . Turning my API_URL into a getter however solved the problem.

Comment: Okay well if it's resolved no need to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to change your `API_URL` to **getter**

```
private get API_URL () {
   return this.startupService.startupData.fleetApi;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Once upon a time, I solved this same scenario by using `APP_INITIALIZER`

https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER

https://devblog.dymel.pl/2017/10/17/angular-preload/